# Get service status of Centreon results in 404

Tags: python, centreon-api

I need to get all of service status in Centreon using REST API. However, I can't retrieve the values at all. It only returns a 404 error.

How can I resolve a problem like this with Centreon?

Here, my code:

```
import requests
import json


def authentification():
    # données authentification
    payload = '{"security": {"credentials": {"login": "XXXXXXXXXX", "password": "XXXXXXXX"}}}'
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    #requête authentification
    r = requests.post('http://192.168.17.141/centreon/api/beta/login', data=payload, headers=headers)
    #on récupère le token
    json = r.json()
    #initialisation du header pour le token
    headers = dict()
    headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = json['security']['token']
    print(headers)
    return(headers)
    
def get_service_status(authToken):
    #Requête
    headers = {'centreon-auth-token': auth_token}
    response = requests.get('http://192.168.17.141/centreon/api/monitoring/services&search={""}', headers=authToken)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("OK1")
        services = response.json()
        for service in services:
            print(f"Service: {service['description']}, Status: {service['state']}")
    else:
        print(f"Erreur: {response.status_code}")


auth_token = authentification()
get_service_status(auth_token)
```